# Can maven run test when java directory is not directly under test directory?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

Under the default maven folder structure, my maven test runs perfectly. I tried something slightly different by including a directory between the test directory and the java directly. This way, maven could no longer find the test.

This runs OK with `mvn clean install`:

[Works OK with this folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNizK.png)

With the same `mvn clean install`, maven could not find the test here:

[No test to run with this folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Q6e.png)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

No other configuration was made after changing the folder structure. The only major difference between the two structures is that in the second one, there is a directory `demo` between test and java directories. How can maven run the test OK using the second folder structure?

Output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ PGS ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\userhome\test-automation\PGS\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ PGS ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\userhome\test-automation\PGS\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:compile (default-compile) @ PGS ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ PGS ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\userhome\test-automation\PGS\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ PGS ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ PGS ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ PGS ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\userhome\test-automation\PGS\target\PGS-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-cucumber-reporting:5.6.2:generate (execution) @ PGS ---
[INFO] About to generate Cucumber report.
Jun 16, 2022 12:42:19 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder generateErrorPage
INFO: Unexpected error
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: None report file was added!
        at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:61)
        at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:97)
        at net.masterthought.cucumber.CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.execute(CucumberReportGeneratorMojo.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\userhome\test-automation\PGS\pom.xml to C:\Users\userhome\.m2\repository\com\demoproject\testautomation\webapi\PGS\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\PGS-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Comment: Can you show the run output while trying: ` maven could not find the test here:` and what does that mean? Error output ?

Comment: Furthermore the idea is a directory layout which is called convention to work with. `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` etc. The real question is: Why would you like to change that ? And for what purpose?

Comment: You probably have to set [project/build/testSourceDirectory](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-model/maven.html#class_build). But why do you want to do that?

Comment: @khmarbaise, the second folder structure is an existing one which I am kind of compelled to use. As long as there is a way for it to work, I guess its ok to go that way

Comment: “Kind of compelled”??

Comment: The compelling here is that you should follow the convention over configuration paradigm.. and furthermore an existing structure can be renamed (that's called refactoring) as for intention to make the usage of a project easier..based on what I can see the correct structure `src/test/java` already exist with the intermediate part `demo` which does not make sense. You can remove that simply ...

Comment: If you like to create a demo like setup you should make a separate module which shows the usage of something like this..apart from that log output I can that you are using ancient old versions of plugins

Comment: @khmarbaise I have updated the question with the logs/output